# Correct domain name for a home desktop Linux machine

Tags: linux, networking, debian, hostname, domain-name

I have several machines running Debian, and during install, I left the `domain name` field blank. This hasn't affected anything so far, but I'm curious what the correct thing to set that field to is if you don't have a registered web domain and your IP is dynamically set (http://www.whatsmyip.org/ gives a different IP every few months). Apologies if this is a newb question, but I can't find any results via Google.

What is the proper domain name for a home desktop with a dynamic IP address?

Comment: On [unix.se]: [*Correct domain name for a non-server desktop machine*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190348/21962)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While associating with a domain isn't required, it's still useful to associate with one to avoid problems with hostname lookups of the host in question getting forwarded higher up in the DNS hierarchy. In most cases, having `.local` as domain is appropriate, as you will most likely be behind a router that does not forward your DNS name. I've also seen some systems use `.home` in place of this.

`.local` is considered best-proctice, as a sensible router will not forward requests for hostnames belonging to this domain, so if you for some weird reason have a server named `microsoft.com` at home, it will be treated locally, seeing as its [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) will then be `microsoft.com.local.`

Another approach is what I'm doing since I have various machines and servers spread all over, and at home I use my desktop computer as part of my domain name. My DNS servers has a DNS entry for my desktop, with my router forwarding various services (`ssh`, mainly) to it.

---

Also, I find this to be highly relevant, as changing the domain of a server can be more complicated than changing your legal name.:

[image: My sons name was chosen in 5 minutes, but every time I'm setting up a new machine, I've spent days in advance planning the servers name]
*This hostname is going in dozens of remote config files. Changing a kid's name is comparatively easy!*

Comment: Can you (or someone) please clarify if you mean to use `.local` alone, specifically or something like `foo.local`?

Answer (score 5):

If you won't connect more than a handful of machines at the beginning, but you think it may scale, you can use something in the `.local` TLD (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local)

Something like `yoursurname.local` may be the domain name.

If you don't even think to scale to more than say 10-15 machines, then you don't need a domain name. But if you think you will scale, choosing something non-exotic like the `.local` TLD will allow you to set up a full DNS server later to reach your machines.

**Make sure you read** wikipedia's page; the usage of "somethingcustom.local" as a domain is something that has been done in the past, and is still done inside small businesses. Anyway, as you can see from the page, the `.local` TLD has been reserved for use in mDNS, for host names in the form `hostname.local`, which may collide with your setup. As per RFC 6762 you MAY use alternative lookup methods (e.g. the custom DNS server I recommend to scale up your network) and the result is up to your ability not to mix up data and names...

Answer (score 3):

If this is a single network, and you do not intend setting up a local
mail server or a DNS server that connect to the Internet, then the domain name
is of no importance at all and can be left as blank.

The domain name only serves to combine with the host-name to create the
the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the system.
For example, if the domain name is `company.com` and the host name
is `host1`, then the FQDN is `host1.company.com`.
You will still need to setup a DNS server to resolve that name to an IP address,
or have some Internet DNS server point to your network.

Without a domain name, the computers can still be identified on their network
by their host-name.

Since this is a home desktop being attributed a local IP address via DHCP,
a blank domain name is entirely appropriate. Specifying a domain name
would have no effect at all in that case.

For more info see Wikipedia : [Fully qualified domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).

Answer (score 0):

Under networking logic, if your domain name is not registered to let it be found out via DNS server when someone pings with this domain name, then it will be useless what you decide to type in.

All networking devices, including routers work with IP addresses to reach another device, there is an special protocol to discover the IP address regarding its DNS name (with its domain name) by sending this kind of packages to some DNS server and the DNS server would send the corresponding IP address to know what is the "understandable" recipient. Therefore, it's only relevant if you are going to interconnect your own network with some local DNS server in your local network and set up your hosts to use this local DNS server or if you pay for getting a reachable network via public DNS servers.

Supposing that you have a reachable network via public DNS servers, your PCs that are connected to this network need to be configured like server hosts to talk properly about replying requests to your domain name from another device, because the domain name works with server configuration, hence, if you have your PCs without some server configuration, then the domain name will be useless for your PCs as well.

For more information I provide you Cisco documentation about DNS server, as follows:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dns/configuration/15-mt/dns-15-mt-book/dns-config-dns.html

Or you can check RFC 1034, the official documentation about the protocol that works for it: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).